# How do i Install Windows now?

Tags: boot, windows

i recently bought a new PC and i had no Windows available (my stick broke, had to buy a new one). So i just used a 4 GB Stick to install Ubuntu. Now i though i just can install Windows like normally but i cant event get the windows Iso on my Stick. I used WinUSB and it just stucks at installing for i386-pc some thing some thing. Also i tried using the Methos where i copy the iso files onto the stick, that didnt work either because even tho i changed the boot priority and safe mode + UEFI Boot it still booted to Linux instead of the Windows Installation Programm.
My Question now is: How do i install Windows and Remove Linux (Ubuntu)?
If possible a Version that is very easy! Iam not very technical.
I dont want to Dual Boot or something like that, just want to get rid of Ubuntu and install Windows.

Hope you can Help me.

edit. I do not have a CD nor a Drive for one.

Comment: If you want to install Windows, you need to enter the BIOS boot menu. Tell me the brand of your computer and I can tell you how to do it. Some warnings, though. If you want to install Windows, but keep Ubuntu, you will need to run boot-repair after Windows installs. If you just want to remove Ubuntu and install Windows, follow those links in the comments on your question.

Comment: @EliahKagan I interpreted it to mean he couldn't boot from the USB drive. I don't know if that's right, though. I was giving instructions on how to get into the BIOS boot device selection menu.

Comment: @Zacharee1:  "Tell me the brand of your computer" is a question in itself, so this should have been a comment, not an answer...  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby I know that's a question, and I started it as a comment. The rest of it, though, just felt like an answer.

Comment: @Zacharee1:  Good man!  **;-)**  Never interacted with you before and I prefer my communication too clear over not clear enough...

Answer (score 0):

I would personally make a Windows Bootable Usb using UnetBootin (I found this the most reliable.) *http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/*(link) OR you could use the link *[How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu)* to get Windows bootbale stick.

Then navigate to the Bios and choose the boot order.

You should see something that says USB, follow the controls and move the USB drive to the top.

Restart your pc with your USB stick with Windows on it.

Follow the steps to install Windows and choose the partition that says Ubuntu on it.

That should wipe Ubuntu completely.

Hope this helps

Comment: Rufus is another program that is similar to UNetbootin, and it can also be used to make a Windows bootable USB stick. [Install Windows or Ubuntu from usb drive using Rufus](http://bootableusb.net/install-windows-ubuntu-usb-drive-using-rufus/).